# confused about dummy coding and contrasts

Tags: r, contrasts

Dummy coding refers to use k - 1 variables to represent k level variable in a model, while contrasts assign each parameter for a level (for example, assign 1 to level k1 and -1 to level k2, so as to compare k1 and k2). So I was confused, what is the difference between dummy coding and contrasts, and how did they function in modeling a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dummy coding is called Coding Schemes, and Contrasts is called Contrast Weights. The coding schemes is inverse matrix of contrast weights, and vise versa.

refers to [A (sort of) Complete Guide to Contrasts in R](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/65059_586f394d8eb84f84b1baaf56ffb6b47f.html)